# Sending Keystrokes to a separate Java process

Tags: java, process, runtime, keystroke, keystrokes

I need to be able to send a set of keystrokes from one Java application to the other. I am creating the one that send the keystrokes, but I am unable to modify the receiving end and thus need some sort of method to send them through either the Java runtime or some other work-around method.

If anyone has any information that can point me in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean two different java applications running on different jvms then that means two processes, waht u trying to do is interprocess communication, simply using some socket or file you can do it, memory mapped files also can be used

Comment: Using a socket or a file would be possible but I am unable to modify the other application's code

Comment: if you are on windows platform you can use windows api for window handling but using java that is not possible, you need to code in some other languages like c# or c++